# Spread types may only be created from object types. Problem arrives with Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular9

```
getIssuersCollection() {
return this.afs
  .collection('issuers')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(docArray => {
      return docArray.map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
          ...doc.payload.doc.data()
        };
      });
    })
  );
```

}

The above code worked fine in Angular 8 but throw's an error in Angular 9. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: You should use the `valueChanges` method, which now allows an `idField` property to be set to specify where the document's ID will be mapped to.

Comment: Maybe because `doc.payload.doc.data()` is returning a type of `any`? I suggest to assign it a custom interface/type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Object.assign({},doc.payload.doc.data) instead of it for quick fix i think

or try ...doc.payload.doc.data() as {}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this help but try to revert the order like this

```
return {
          ...doc.payload.doc.data()
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
};
```